# Sparkr convert broadcast RDD to actual value

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr

I sent a broadcast BC to worker node, in my program

```
BC= SparkR:::broadcast(sc, data)
```

I have a function

```
myF=function(x)
{
    allV=SparkR:::value(BC)
    ..... Use allV ......
    return(result)
}
```

Then I called this function

```
finalResult = SparkR:::lapply(currentRDD, myF)
```

However, the error message showed me that allV are still PipelineRDD, what is the correct way to convert allV to actual data?

Many thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand you are trying to broadcast a `RDD` and it is something that doesn't make sense at all. `RDD` is simply a recipe or a description of transformations and doesn't contain actual data.

To get the results you have to trigger an action, like `collect`, but Spark doesn't support nested actions or transformations so what you're trying to achieve is not possible.

If data is small enough to be handled locally you should `collect` first and broadcast a local data structure. If it is not possible you can `join` RDDs.

And once again, internal API is internal for a reason :)